# Converting standard database datetime format to SOQL datetime format using Salesforce SOQL(Salesforce Object Query Language)

Tags: sql, salesforce, informatica-powercenter, soql

Table1 is source table in Salesforce

Source SOQL:

```
Select col1,col2,col3 from Table1
  where lastmodifieddate > $ExtractStartDate
```

LastModifiedDate column is providing timestamp data from salesforce. Extract Start Date is parameterized in Informatica and the value is getting replaced by Informatica mapping as standard timestamp, so the query is changing dynamically to

```
Select col1,col2,col3 from Table
  where lastmodifieddate > 2021-01-01 16:01:00
```

but salesforce is expecting date in 2021-01-01T16:01:00Z

Please shed some light on how to convert date time format from 2021-01-01 16:01:00 to 2021-01-01T16:01:00Z

Comment: can you not replace the space with T and concat Z in SOQL like this  - `REPLACE($ExtractStartDate,' ','T' )||'Z'` ?

Comment: it throws error unexpected token error in SOQL